# How to use "this" keyword in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting column data using `@Input()` like this

```
@Input() columns: any;
```

I checked in `ngOnInit()` also by consoling, it getting the data also. But still getting above error in `successTextColorCondition()` method

```
    export class GridComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private excelExportService: IgxExcelExporterService, 
              private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef,
              private localeService:LocaleService) {
               }
  paginationSetting: GridPagination;

  // Inputs
  
  @Input() columns: Array<GridColumn>;


  @ViewChild('grid', { static: true }) public grid: IgxGridComponent;
  
  public successTextColorCondition(rowData: any, columnKey: any): boolean {
    console.log('columns', this.columns)
    return rowData[columnKey] === 'Success'
  }
  private failureTextColorCondition(rowData: any, columnKey: any): boolean{
    return rowData[columnKey] === 'Failure'
  }
  textColorChangeClasses = {
    successText: this.successTextColorCondition,
    failureText: this.failureTextColorCondition,
  };
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('columns1', this.columns)
    this.setDefaultConfig();
    this.setDefaultPaginationConfig();
  }
  
}
```

But I am getting error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined
```

Is there anything I did wrong?

I also checked how to access this in callback function, but I am not able to understand. Please can anyone help in this?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @GuyIncognito I already checked that blog but didn't understood

Comment: Please share the code of the entire class

Comment: Would you please provide a minimal reproducible code example as a starting point, for example, an Angular project in https://stackblitz.com/. It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Lonely for creating stackblitz for this demo will take time. I already added entire code. If you need anything else then please tell

Comment: Dear Ashish, I think it is a timing problem, to analyze it, we need the big picture every time. If you want someone to help you quickly, make it a habit to always organize a StickBlitz beforehand. If it takes you time to do this, I can understand. Please understand, however, that answering takes time too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is call back function
make changes

```
textColorChangeClasses = {
    successText: this.successTextColorCondition.bind(this),
    failureText: this.failureTextColorCondition,
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try changing

```
  textColorChangeClasses = {
    successText: this.successTextColorCondition,
    failureText: this.failureTextColorCondition,
  };
```

to

```
  textColorChangeClasses = {
    successText: (rowData: any, columnKey: any) => this.successTextColorCondition(rowData, columnKey),
    failureText: this.failureTextColorCondition,
  };
```

or

```
  textColorChangeClasses = {
    successText: this.successTextColorCondition.bind(this),
    failureText: this.failureTextColorCondition,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

```
public successTextColorCondition(rowData: any, columnKey: any): boolean {
    console.log('columns', this.columns()) //<--why columns is called as function?
    return rowData[columnKey] === 'Success'
  }
```

Second, `@Input` and `@ViewChild` should be right on the top before constructor (some editors might complain)

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @Input() columns: Array<GridColumn>;
    @ViewChild('grid', { static: true }) public grid: IgxGridComponent;

    constructor(){...}
```

Comment: Sorry, this.column is not a function, it a typing error. Its a variable which is got from @Input()

Comment: And i shifted my @Input and @Viewchild() but still getting the same error

Comment: If that's the entire code, your code looks fine......perhaps clear the browser cache & run your application again.

Comment: I did, same happened. I think it is some callback function issue. But I am not able to understand what to do

Comment: how are you using `textColorChangeClasses`? perhaps paste the entire ts & html file.